# using word VBA, how to find that the value in arr2 are present in arr1?

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is my logic

```
arr(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
arr1(3,4,5)
arr2(2,0)
arr3(6,7,45,8,3)


(arr,arr1)....-> True
(arr,arr2)....-> False
(arr,arr3)....-> False
```

using word VBA, how to find that the value in arr2 must present in arr? if one of the value in arr2 didn't match with arr then it should come out of the particular array(Example: arr2(0,9)) and then start checking with next array(arr3). I want to compare one **arr** with multiple arrays**(arr1,arr2,arr3)**. I tried the below mentioned logic.

```
For j = 1 To UBound(arr1)
            For k = 1 To UBound(arr2)
               If arr1(j) = arr2(k) Then

                     \\.......

              End If
            Next
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
Sub TestMatched()
    Dim Arr() As Variant

    Arr = Array(33, 4, 15)
    Debug.Print Matched(Arr)
End Sub

Private Function Matched(Arr2() As Variant) As Long

    Dim Arr1() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    For i = LBound(Arr2) To UBound(Arr2)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Arr2(i), Arr1, 0)) Then
            Matched = Arr2(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: My requirement is different. Thanks for your reply sir... arr(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
arr1(3,4,5)
arr2(2,0)
arr3(6,7,45,8,3)


(arr,arr1)....-> True
(arr,arr2)....-> False
(arr,arr3)....-> False